# Implementing Symfony Kernel with custom Routing Mechanism

Tags: php, url-routing, symfony-2.3, symfony-http-kernel

I am trying to implement Symfony Kernel into a legacy application I developed which had a custom mechanism for handling URL routing.

Is there a way of replacing the routing mechanism supplied by Symfony and just use the legacy one?

Comment: need an answer too